# How can i delete page cache using php?

Tags: magento2

When a customer changes the custom data from his account page , on the main page returns the old data, but in the database it changes , Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento way you can achieve by below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cacheManager = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Manager');
$cacheManager->clean($cacheManager->getAvailableTypes());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the cache programmatically by calling the 
`\Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface::remove()` method.

Let me know if you have any confusion for implementation.